# Improving a model attribute for better efficiency and usability

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Framework:** Laravel 5.1

**Background:** I have a `Product` and a `ProductVariation` model, which both share a `ImplementsProductAttributes` trait. If a `Product` is variable, than the product should contain at least a single purchasable `ProductVariation` to be purchasable, rest of the logic would be obvious within the code sample from the trait. Functionality works as is.

```
public function getPurchasableAttribute()
{
    if ($this instanceof \App\Product)
    {
        if ($this->type == 'variable')
        {
            foreach ($this->variations as $variation)
            {
                if ($variation->purchasable)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        else return $this->isItemPurchasable();
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->isItemPurchasable();
    }
}

public function isItemPurchasable()
{
    if($this->regular_price > 0 AND $this->published)
    {
        if ($this->manage_stock) 
        {
            return $this->stock_quantity > 0;
        }
        else return $this->in_stock;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

**Pros:**

- I make use of laravels attributes,
- Readable/maintainable code,

**Cons:**

- Redundant eager loading on the variations (which could be a problem
  if this was supposed to be used on an API)
- Redundant SQL queries (I could implement a single query to get a
  count in the end, and decide based on that if the product itself is
  purchasable, but instead I am loading all variations -- at least
  until i get one with purchasable=true --)

**Question:** Should I keep this implementation or should I improve by getting rid of pulling relationships and making a simple SQL query to get the purchasable variations?

Please elaborate on your answer as much as you can.

**Edit**: Also please let me know if you think any other pros/cons exist.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as per the concern of coding standard, you can get rid of this nested if-else structure in getPurchasableAttribute() method like this

```
public function getPurchasableAttribute()
{
    if (!( $this instanceof \App\Product) ||  $this->type != 'variable')
    {
        return $this->isItemPurchasable();
    }

    foreach ($this->variations as $variation)
    {
        if ($variation->purchasable)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Can you please tell something more about $variation->purchasable

Is purchasable an eloquent relationship defined in $variation or an attribute of $variation.

So that we can talk something more on efficiency.

Comment: as I told, getPurchasableAttribute is an attribute, defined on both Product and ProductVariation (via a Trait) which is a bool that defines if that product or the variation is purchasable or not. so the code stays same for both of the models. Thanks for the tip on nested if-else structure, I guess this is more readable to me.